# pass multiple variables in url in php

Tags: php

i have one variable like this

```
$groupid=$_GET['groupid'];
```

and in the same page i have one button like this..

```
  <td>
      <a href="assigncoursedelete.php?id=<?php echo $row->id;?>" onclick="return confirm('Are you sure you wish to delete this Record?');">
      <div style="background-color:#CD5C5C; width:30px; padding-left:9px; padding-top:3px; height:28px; color:white">
      <em class="fa fa-trash"></em></div>
  </td>
```

and i want to pass that `$groupid` variable in the above URL..

I tried but its not passing the variable to the delete page..

Can anyone help me how to do this..

Thanks in advance..

Comment: I'd advise using the POST http method for deletions via HTML.  Browsers/robots can prefetch/follow links and it results in disaster.

Answer (score 1):

```
<td><a href="assigncoursedelete.php?id=<?php echo $row->id;?>&groupid=<?php echo $groupid; ?>" onclick="return confirm('Are you sure you wish to delete this Record?');"><div style="background-color:#CD5C5C; width:30px; padding-left:9px; padding-top:3px; height:28px; color:white">
                                      <em class="fa fa-trash"></em></div></td>
```

Will this work for you try it

Answer (score 1):

```
assigncoursedelete.php?id=<?php echo $row->id;?>&groupid=<?php echo $groupid; ?>
```

you must use '&' to pass multiple data  in URL

Comment: then please accept it as valid answer. Glad to help.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this :-

```
<td>
  <a href="assigncoursedelete.php?id=<?php echo $row->id."&groupid=".$groupid;?>" onclick="return confirm('Are you sure you wish to delete this Record?');">
  <div style="background-color:#CD5C5C; width:30px; padding-left:9px; padding-top:3px; height:28px; color:white">
  <em class="fa fa-trash"></em></div>
</td>
```

Happy Coding :-)

Answer (score 0):

Use the php `http_build_query` function.  It will take care of possible encoding issues:

```
<?php
$data = [
    'id' => 47,
    'name' => 'this & that'
];

$url = 'destination.php?=' . http_build_query($data, '', '&amp;');
?>
<a href="<?= $url ?>">Do something</a>
```

Output:

```
<a href="destination.php?=id=47&amp;name=this+%26+that">Do something</a>
```